# Crosstab query with date criteria

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have created a crosstab query as below

```
TRANSFORM Nz(Sum([debit]*[GeneralExpenses]),0) AS mOmomeya
SELECT Expenses.sName, Expenses.ArName
FROM (GL INNER JOIN Expenses ON GL.ID = Expenses.glID) INNER JOIN Transactions ON GL.GL = Transactions.GL
GROUP BY Expenses.sName, Expenses.ArName
PIVOT Month([ddate]);
```

what I want to do is to add a criteria to the [dDate] field from a form text input to match the date that I entered, but I received error while doing this as below

[image]

any idea what's wrong?

Comment: So do you only want to perform that calculation for one specific date?

Comment: Only to set criteria for the date of transaction between 2 dates entered inside 2 text boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, there definitely seems to be something a little bit different about crosstab queries. The straight SELECT query...

```
SELECT expenses.*
FROM expenses
WHERE (((expenses.ddate) Between [Forms]![main]![DateFrom] And [Forms]![main]![DateTo]));
```

...works fine, but the crosstab query...

```
TRANSFORM Sum(expenses.expenses) AS SumOfexpenses
SELECT expenses.onduty
FROM expenses
WHERE (((expenses.ddate) Between [Forms]![main]![DateFrom] And [Forms]![main]![DateTo]))
GROUP BY expenses.onduty
PIVOT Month(ddate);
```

...fails with the error message you cited. One workaround would be to rebuild the SQL for the query before using it:

```
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("yourCrosstab")
qdf.SQL = _
        "TRANSFORM Nz(Sum([debit]*[GeneralExpenses]),0) AS mOmomeya " & _
        "SELECT Expenses.sName, Expenses.ArName " & _
        "FROM (GL INNER JOIN Expenses ON GL.ID = Expenses.glID) INNER JOIN Transactions ON GL.GL = Transactions.GL " & _
        "WHERE (((ddate) " & _
            "Between #" & Format(CDate([Forms]![main]![DateFrom]), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# " & _
            "And #" & Format(CDate([Forms]![main]![DateTo]), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#)) " & _
        "GROUP BY Expenses.sName, Expenses.ArName " & _
        "PIVOT Month(ddate);"
Set qdf = Nothing
DoCmd.OpenQuery "yourCrosstab"  '' or whatever you want to do with it
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that crosstab querys require the form parameter for each form. Right click on gray space and select parameter. Put in the forms and data type.